# CSS hack for Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: css, firefox, ubuntu

I find the question on stackoverflow related to font issue and because of that alignment problem on Ubuntu FF.

After reading that question's answer, I understood that on Ubuntu may be the font is not by default installed like "Arial", "verdana" etc.

So, can somebody tell me how to put a css hack for Ubuntu OS Firefox so that all things work properly.

Note: I need not to change the font, the ubuntu FF will do this automatically when it will not find the default font, I only need to updated the letter-spacing and word-spacing of the font.

Is there any hack style available for Ubuntu FF? like for IE6 it is "_" and for IE 7 it is "*"?

Thanks

Comment: which question is "the question"?

Comment: Hi, now I've edited my question and hope you can understand what I want to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this font here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_Sans

> These fonts are metric-compatible with Monotype Corporation's Arial, Times New Roman, and Courier New (respectively),

So basically, you'll be looking to adding **Liberation Sans** in your font stack.

```
font-family: Arial, Liberation Sans, sans-serif;
```

Do note that Verdana is a poor substitute for Arial, as the two have very different widths.